# react router race condition

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I've a react-router-dom and redux. My scenario is quite simple:
1) If the user doesn't have token redirect to login
2) Otherwise go to dashboard.
The problem is that the redux check for the token (in the local-storage) arrive a bit later so whatever I do I got redirect to login.This is my

code:

```
const AsyncAuth = asyncComponent(() => import('containers/Auth/Auth'));
const AsyncDashboard = asyncComponent(() => import('containers/Dashboard/Dashboard'));
interface IProps {
  autoSignIn: () => void;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
}
class App extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.props.autoSignIn();
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/auth" component={AsyncAuth} />
          {this.props.isAuthenticated && <Route path="/dashboard" component={AsyncDashboard} />}
          <Redirect to="/auth" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.idToken !== null
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  autoSignIn: () => dispatch(authAutoSignIn())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the redux code but I assume your `autoSignIn` action creator performs an async action. What you could do is in the reducer for `state.auth` keep some state like `triedAutoLogin: false`.

Whenever your async login action resolves (either successfully/unsuccessfully) you can update `triedAutoLogin: true`. Then include that in your `mapStateToProps` and render the `<Route /> and <Redirect />` component conditionally based on both.

Comment: nope it's sync: [link]https://github.com/daniele-zurico/typescript-private-example/blob/master/src/store/actions/auth.ts#L29

Comment: On the other side is not correct what you saying because isAuthenticated is false by default looking on state.auth.idToken !== null

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern when working with redux-thunk (and Flux Standard Actions) is to have a `requestStatus` property.

It's usually for HTTP request, you'd have `NotStarted`, 'Initiated', 'Success', and 'Failed'.

You can apply a similar style to your Redux.

You can have an `authCheckStatus` property, with the same values.

And in the component, instead of rendering the router, you render something else (nothing, if the check is fast enough), when `authCheckStatus` is not `Success`.

That would be separate from the `idToken` itself.